# Add new listrow is giving me a row number 2 on from the last row instead of just 1

Tags: excel, vba

I am extracting data from one workbook row by row, columns A to CA (79 columns). I'm adding each row to a table in a new workbook, columns B to CB. Column A is a formula. I have the new workbook set up as an excel table. I'm extracting the source workbook row into an array, then assigning that array to the table in a new row. (listrows.add). (I've deleted all rows except row 1 at the start of the program & cleared contents for columns B to CB in row 1).

When I've assigned the array, column A formula calculates a unique ID (which will then be used to add a new worksheet with that ID name).

The problem I'm having is that when I add the 2nd row as a new row, newrow.index is 2, as expected, but instead of newrow.range.row being 4 as it should be (headers are in row 2), it's 5. And when I reference newrow.range(newrow.index,1) I get "" (as if it was using row 5) instead of the value which is in newrow.range(2,1).

I feel like this might be an array problem and I may have stared at this for too long but I can't see why it's skipping two rows.

Here's the code where the problem lies.

```
Sub importdata()
Dim lastrw As Long
Dim lastcl As Long
Dim newrow As ListRow
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim v As Variant

    lastrw = lastrow(1, sourcesheet)
    lastcl = lastcolumn(1, sourcesheet)

    ReDim v(1 To 1, 1 To lastcl)

    For i = 2 To lastrw
        If i = 2 Then
            Set newrow = applicationtable.ListRows(1)
        Else
            Set newrow = applicationtable.ListRows.Add(alwaysinsert:=True)
        End If
        v = sourcesheet.Range(sourcesheet.Cells(i, 1), sourcesheet.Cells(i, lastcl))
        newrow.Range.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, lastcl) = v
        Debug.Print ".index " & newrow.Index
        Debug.Print ".row " & newrow.Range(newrow.Index, 1).Row
        Debug.Print ".value " & newrow.Range(newrow.Index, 1)
        Call copytemplate(newrow.Range(newrow.Index, 1), i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

debug.print index gives 2 (as it should be after newrow added)

debug.print row gives 5 (it should be 4. listrow(1) is in row 3, so listrow(2) 
should be in row 4).

debug.print value gives "".

sourcesheet is globally declared and is my source data
applicationtable is globally declared and is my destination table

Comment: applicationtable.databodyrange(newrow.index,1) refers to the correct cell, which newrow.range(newrow.index,1) doesn't. The row is still incorrect (says 5 instead of 4 ) but as I can use databodyrange to reference the correct cell then I'm doing that for now. I'd still like to know why the other references are wrong, if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: You are comparing ListRows with SheetRangeRows.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing ListRows and SheetRows. `newrow` is a ListRow. Its Index property holds the number of that row in the table. `newrow.Range(mewrow.Index, 1)` is a worksheet range and its Row property returns the sheet row number.

BTW, `ReDim v(1 To 1, 1 To lastcl)` is superfluous because v will take another dimension here: `v = SourceSheet.Range(SourceSheet.Cells(i, 1), SourceSheet.Cells(i, lastcl))`. Observe also that `SourceSheet.Range(SourceSheet.Cells(i, 1), SourceSheet.Cells(i, lastcl))` defines a range which you are assigning to v. That is perfectly valid but what you trust Excel to understand is that you don't mean the range. You mean to assign the `Value` of that range to v. Your code will be more readable and less prone to being misunderstood, especially by yourself, if you say what you mean, i.e. `v = SourceSheet.Range(SourceSheet.Cells(i, 1), SourceSheet.Cells(i, lastcl)).Value`.

The same applies here: `newrow.Range.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, lastcl) = v`
What you mean is `newrow.Range.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, lastcl).Value = v`. Observe that `newrow.Range` is a sheet range, not a range of the ListObject (It makes no difference here but you need the Offset). You are resizing it to the size of v implicitly. The better way is to do so explicitly. Such as,

```
newrow.Range.Cells(1).Resize(UBound(v), UBound(v, 2)).Value = v
```